# Why does RSA decryption fail in python when encrypted in js?

Tags: python, node.js, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm creating python server and js client. To authenticate users, I used RSA. After server sent public key, client encrypt msg using js 'crypto' module and return encrypted message. But I can't decrypt message in server using python 'cryptography'.

Here is my server(python) code.

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
import socketio
from aiohttp import web
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes

sio = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='aiohttp', cors_allowed_origins='*')
app = web.Application()
sio.attach(app)

def main(): //key import from .pem
    with open("private_key.pem", "rb") as key_file:
        key.private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
            key_file.read(),
            password=None,
            backend=default_backend()
        )
    with open("public_key.pem", "rb") as key_file:
        key.public_key = serialization.load_pem_public_key(
            key_file.read(),
            backend=default_backend()
        )
    #Serialize to send as a message
    key.public_key_serialization = key.public_key.public_bytes(
        encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
        format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
    )
    print(key.private_key_serialization.decode("utf-8"))

@sio.event
async def get_public_key(sid, data):
    await sio.emit('public_key', {
        'public': key.public_key_serialization.decode('utf-8'), #send public key
        'data': encrypted}, room=sid)

def decrypt(sid, data): #decrypt from encrypted message
    original_message = key.private_key.decrypt(
        data["data"],
        padding.OAEP(
            mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
            label=None
        )
    )
    print(original_message)
```

the data["data"] is the encrypted message like b"'\xf5N\xb9\xe9\xfd\xac\x84'\xc9\x1dKkc\xb2%\xb7\xd2\xcb\x1a4\x8c\xean\xf2\x9b\xab^\xb9\x . . .

It is my client(js) code.

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
var buffer =require('buffer').Buffer;
const io = require("socket.io-client");
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

var msg = crypto.publicEncrypt({
        key: data["public"],
        oaepHash: 'sha256'
    }, buffer.from("encrypt me!")) #ciphertext: encrypt me!
    console.log(msg)
```

(editor recognizes below text as code..)

```
the data["public"] is 
 -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAwvZD07r1IDHYMnDZqVql
glro/loIY9lUTpqdKaZigB0XE82pyDiqPZA2jzgxkAQJBKRO5u5PiN+UC2Ur5oqM
fQUyDefsKuC5c5rpnJK1px6IsjDzCym5DPXZoVbb7nYzmy0rLLwQZC/hZqIiuP/Y
y+3Orz49I+KSI4Lhq2kRWYhLUUhecdF+AJndkbZtWjsW1wc1tsCV0knQuVilPpwe
OmGgYQD/5xqcJRHHsYryGxFMW/2YJ1eD+3EzEUpRkXxaHIc9Uagc8TbT8uVbeoXi
Zrbl2BkfO6O8swBF+VgG3d6qZZoEyrk2TS3rB6oQSQWPFVissh4sFVOcjh37hdB2
BwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

private key is

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpgIBAAKCAQEAwvZD07r1IDHYMnDZqVqlglro/loIY9lUTpqdKaZigB0XE82p
yDiqPZA2jzgxkAQJBKRO5u5PiN+UC2Ur5oqMfQUyDefsKuC5c5rpnJK1px6IsjDz
Cym5DPXZoVbb7nYzmy0rLLwQZC/hZqIiuP/Yy+3Orz49I+KSI4Lhq2kRWYhLUUhe
cdF+AJndkbZtWjsW1wc1tsCV0knQuVilPpweOmGgYQD/5xqcJRHHsYryGxFMW/2Y
J1eD+3EzEUpRkXxaHIc9Uagc8TbT8uVbeoXiZrbl2BkfO6O8swBF+VgG3d6qZZoE
yrk2TS3rB6oQSQWPFVissh4sFVOcjh37hdB2BwIDAQABAoIBAQCdxH961W4L0Yos
t1nMTEhnRn4JZn4nnvU0brYDwFsxZVkJc4KTPhe1ngAowcaJzlol4XjgM7U1BAhf
eE2gUDoD6bJpwmZBBH3OaWvmgmpxhKoF2Mq1G9xd+o1UnF95hzmXt2Oa3c095ek3
Drmej5u22whIk8sSQQUVq5JHDc02b0U/XyBHn+OqNMYn7EFsYHeSUMIcx58bQ/u4
Tvi0NdEovVciURFq173XM+BK+8oRnJBpEglskWfA6kuu5+NlpQgkzIM9vDutQyL0
Y9rJGxg3CvTQhn8vZx6COPyLRXTPc6IOExpwsTVmRAshGxbMbt6yXErCagge7VQh
mNymoqNRAoGBAOB2He8Ge7/tXeuTAptb6vgbNeoUjBxFNYmpDnEbplnM9Ydmgy/k
//2lNOu8bRTxk2wVKx35br/BcrJTlTmjzd2CYWJvBKQ9vYznAX2gVJ4MZXX/vHNO
GZEc1bwn5TaxUwywl0Q51TLT6KlHF+PBIttkQjCErbDhnMlrojlyNGw1AoGBAN5b
DY01XgKIUWegt4pRVG+LiQ+Oz547ksWIM338QP7o6BFLn85jAdByFmt94xgEUe4c
5FNRfZWOgbNLUSlbQ6AmUFVPDr3xfQDEKk65ci9dK4t/S7rajuHGHHzhW8wV/bYp
m7/N5ax0FEsyuJQpP0e0KambT1EJnWti6SERCQjLAoGBAMPers5XJQPdeZjJZ3v0
4PzymcCTf5Rn3IktChovm6E/Vn56OT5BIhXP5XdUrQeaqx+k9UQp1rfkclck0tJC
m7GRRbPk1vMPoWnkZ4udrllgzeUDbgpce7kCpYyUb9OjN6qaKtXxdZbuDlgxXqpz
bhxux8eY8AyrQ+sMTrq8avyFAoGBANOQJvC4Wl5mfa3vyTKd94y6YwqegwS3AgtY
cEXrAZyI1mW+YqrooQ1Hv/U+rhhn49x/OO/dlXP7R4TkoLCM2WdDjSPeONSZNKrJ
+sc0w2Q1bf0ofVGoKlK/QNPBSKqCMghkxoBU07amK7jw5ZZzOHZtAUcTMwCT+Wf3
kIGZx9LJAoGBAIWbpW1FIGiTJUzQDa2Y2n0S3P7vMpAI1YlIC32hGzKjtwKR4sWr
jqIgj7Zw67u3O8h0lwqyAMFxoMBfBbc2A3ctapPwHEs6TFqA5c1WKptt9LiqrP7n
oaD+XcUrgIed4gSa4KoXPoo2AFu3eyFq47/6jmV9rS42hut8s+KAds7r
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

According the docs, both use OAEP padding.

python cryptography - [https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#:~:text=RSA%20private%20key.-,decrypt,-(ciphertext%2C%20padding)](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#:%7E:text=RSA%20private%20key.-,decrypt,-(ciphertext%2C%20padding))

js crypto - https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_privatedecrypt_privatekey_buffer

I really don't know why it is failed.. Any advise, comments and suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try encrypting/decrypting with the same library - js with js and python with python?

Comment: @gimix Yes. I received both private key and public key from the server. And I tried to encrypting/decrypting in js client using this keys. It success but I can't encrypt in client and decrypt in server.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue on my machine by taking your code, adding the missing parts (e.g. key import) and using my own keys. Maybe your private key does not belong to your public key or you make a mistake with the key import. You should post test keys (private and public) and extend the posted code to a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (including key import).

Comment: @Topaco I added code at server side. If you have succeeded in this process, can you tell me what the problem is with my code?

Comment: I do not know. I can only tell you that the posted code works on my machine (using my keys). For further analysis, post a test key pair and a corresponding ciphertext.

Comment: @Topaco Thank for your help. I attached my key pair and a ciphertext. I tried to encrypting/decrypting with this in client and succeeded but I can't decrypting in server. Is it possible that the encrypted data that the server receives(b'p\x90Q"\xac\x02\xbfx\xf0_~\x06\xf7\x18$\x125\x8f\x9fz\x16\xe9 . . .) is the problem?

Comment: Maybe, you should check if the ciphertext generated on the encryption side is the same as the ciphertext received on the decryption side. By the way, your test keys work.

Comment: @Topaco The representation of the encrypted data is different but the content is same on both server side and client side. Thank you again for your reply. I'll look for more data.